# Getting 5586 event id error with SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, error, owstimer

> Please find the logs from server
>
> 05/12/2017 05:59:11.30  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x2DF8)             0x13A0
>   SharePoint Foundation Database             880i        High
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
>   allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26
>   - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
>   newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
>   userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean
>   applyTransientFaultHandling)     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions)     at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool
>   pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options,
>   DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)     at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection)     at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection)     at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
>   allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)     at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)     at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
>   connection)     at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry)     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.OpenConnection() 
>   ClientConnectionId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000  Error
>   Number:-1,State:0,Class:20
>
> 05/12/2017 05:59:11.30  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x2DF8)             0x13A0
>   SharePoint Foundation Database             880k       High          at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.ExecuteReader(SqlCommand
>   command, CommandBehavior behavior, SqlQueryData monitoringData,
>   Boolean retryForDeadLock)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.ExecuteReader(SqlCommand
>   command, Boolean retryForDeadLock)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.ExecuteReader(SqlCommand
>   command)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Diagnostics.SPDiagnosticsXEventQueryDataProvider.ClearLegacySessions(String
>   connString)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Diagnostics.SPDiagnosticsXEventQueryDataProvider.CreateAndStartCollector(SPDatabaseServiceInstance
>   dbInstance)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Diagnostics.SPDiagnosticsXEventQueryDataProvider.InspectDatabaseServers()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Diagnostics.SPDiagnosticsXEventQueryDataProvider.DoWork()
>   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)     at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)     at
>   System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
>   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
>
> 05/12/2017 05:59:11.30  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x2DF8)             0x13A0
>   SharePoint Foundation Database             880j        High
>   SqlError: 'A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)'    Source: '.Net SqlClient Data Provider' Number: -1
>   State: 0 Class: 20 Procedure: '' LineNumber: 0 Server: ''
>
> 05/12/2017 05:59:11.30  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x2DF8)             0x13A0
>   SharePoint Foundation Database             5586       Critical
>   Unknown SQL Exception -1 occurred. Additional error information from
>   SQL Server is included below.  A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The
>   server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance
>   name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error
>   Locating Server/Instance Specified)
>
> 05/12/2017 05:59:11.30  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x2DF8)             0x13A0
>   SharePoint Foundation Database             tzku       High
>   ConnectionString: 'Data
>   Source=TONSQLSHAQN01.genpitfi01.og.ge.com\ONSQLSHAQN01;Initial
>   Catalog=Master;Integrated Security=True'    Partition: NULL
>   ConnectionState: Closed ConnectionTimeout: 15
>
> 05/12/2017 05:59:11.30  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x2DF8)             0x13A0
>   SharePoint Foundation Database             fa43       High
>   Slow Query Duration: 29424.5943967739
>
> 05/12/2017 05:59:11.30  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x2DF8)             0x13A0
>   SharePoint Foundation Database             fa44       High
>   Slow Query StackTrace-Managed:    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.OnPostExecuteCommand(SqlCommand
>   command, SqlQueryData monitoringData)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.ExecuteReader(SqlCommand
>   command, CommandBehavior behavior, SqlQueryData monitoringData,
>   Boolean retryForDeadLock)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.ExecuteReader(SqlCommand
>   command, Boolean retryForDeadLock)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.ExecuteReader(SqlCommand
>   command)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Diagnostics.SPDiagnosticsXEventQueryDataProvider.ClearLegacySessions(String
>   connString)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Diagnostics.SPDiagnosticsXEventQueryDataProvider.CreateAndStartCollector(SPDatabaseServiceInstance
>   dbInstance)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Diagnostics.SPDiagnosticsXEventQueryDataProvider.InspectDatabaseServers()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Diagnostics.SPDiagnosticsXEventQueryDataProvider.DoWork()
>   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)     at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)     at
>   System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
>   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
>
> 05/12/2017 05:59:11.30  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x2DF8)             0x13A0
>   SharePoint Foundation Database             tzkv        High
>   SqlCommand: 'SELECT name FROM sys.server_event_sessions WHERE name
>   LIKE 'SharePoint_Diagnostics%' and startup_state=0'     CommandType:
>   Text CommandTimeout: 30
>
> 05/12/2017 05:59:11.30  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x2DF8)             0x13A0
>   SharePoint Foundation Database             aek90    High
>   SecurityOnOperationCheck = False
>
> 05/12/2017 05:59:11.30  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x2DF8)             0x13A0
>   SharePoint Foundation Database             880i        High
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
>   allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26
>   - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
>   newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
>   userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean
>   applyTransientFaultHandling)     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions)     at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool
>   pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options,
>   DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)     at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection)     at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection)     at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
>   allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)     at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)     at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
>   connection)     at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry)     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.OpenConnection()     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.ExecuteReader(SqlCommand
>   command, CommandBehavior behavior, SqlQueryData monitoringData,
>   Boolean retryForDeadLock) 
>   ClientConnectionId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000  Error
>   Number:-1,State:0,Class:20
>
> 05/12/2017 05:59:11.30  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x2DF8)             0x13A0
>   SharePoint Foundation Database             880k       High          at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.ExecuteReader(SqlCommand
>   command, Boolean retryForDeadLock)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.ExecuteReader(SqlCommand
>   command)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Diagnostics.SPDiagnosticsXEventQueryDataProvider.ClearLegacySessions(String
>   connString)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Diagnostics.SPDiagnosticsXEventQueryDataProvider.CreateAndStartCollector(SPDatabaseServiceInstance
>   dbInstance)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Diagnostics.SPDiagnosticsXEventQueryDataProvider.InspectDatabaseServers()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Diagnostics.SPDiagnosticsXEventQueryDataProvider.DoWork()
>   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)     at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)     at
>   System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
>   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
>
> 05/12/2017 05:59:11.30  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x2DF8)             0x13A0
>   SharePoint Foundation Database             880j        High
>   SqlError: 'A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)'    Source: '.Net SqlClient Data Provider' Number: -1
>   State: 0 Class: 20 Procedure: '' LineNumber: 0 Server: ''
>
> 05/12/2017 05:59:11.30  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x2DF8)             0x13A0
>   SharePoint Foundation Database             5586       Critical
>   Unknown SQL Exception -1 occurred. Additional error information from
>   SQL Server is included below.  A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The
>   server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance
>   name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error
>   Locating Server/Instance Specified)
>
> Suggest me what could be the reason for causing the issue,thanks for
>   your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sql server pointing to the wrong instance hence we are getting the error removed the wrong sql server instance from CA now we are not receiving any alerts.